# aaai.sty problem with 'Abstract' section

Tags: pdftex

The [AAAI LaTeX style file 'aaai.sty'](http://www.aaai.org/Publications/Templates/aaai.sty) defines the abstract section as follows:

```
\renewenvironment{abstract}{\centerline{\bf
Abstract}\vspace{0.5ex}\begin{quote}\small}{\par\end{quote}\vskip 1ex}
```

However I can't get it to work properly.

If I use:

```
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\abstract  
  This is an abstract of my paper.
\section{Introduction}
  My introduction...
\include{biblio}
\end{document}
```

Though my document view shows the title, abstract, and introduction, I get an error on the `\end{document}` line stating:

```
\begin{quote} on input line 83 ended by \end{document}. \end{document}
```

The bibtex part doesn't run because of the error.
I can't seem to find a latex example using the aaai.sty online to help me, so I've posted here.

If I need to post more information, please indicate what is needed.  Cheers.

Comment: It is defining an environment, so use it as such, thus `\begin/end{abstract} `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The abstract is (as in most, but not all classes) an environment. So use

```
\begin{abstract} 
... 
\end{abstract}
```